# Syntax highlighting with multiple matches with `\zs`

Tags: syntax-highlighting

The string that I have is this `aaabbbb`.  `aaa` must become red, `bbbb` must become blue.

I tried this:

```
" here xB is not matched
syntax match xA /^a\+/
syntax match xB /^a\+\zsb\+/
highlight xA ctermfg=red
highlight xB ctermfg=blue

" here xB is matched
syntax match xB /^a\+\zsb\+/
highlight xB ctermfg=blue
```

But it fails.  1st one only matches `aaa` into red, and misses `bbbb`.

The 2nd one matches `bbbb` into blue, but obviously leaves `aaa` uncolored.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work because Vim won't scan the same text twice trying to match a different regex.

Even though the `\zs` makes the resulting match only include the `b`s, Vim needs to see all the `a`s to be able to match that regex and it won't do so if it already matched the `a`s to the other pattern.

You can do a small experiment to see this behavior, by doing a simple search for the two regexes:

```
/^a\+\|^a\+\zsb\+
```

You'll see that the search will match the `a`s, but not the `b`s.

(On the other hand, replacing the `a` in the first regex with a different character matches both lines starting with that other character *and* lines with the `b`s following the `a`s, which proves the regex otherwise works as expected.)

To work around this issue, use a zero-width lookup match, using [`\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D) to match the series of `a`s at the start of the line preceding the `b`s.

You can use this match instead:

```
syntax match xB /\(^a\+\)\@<=b\+/
```

You'll notice this pattern also works correctly in the search experiment:

```
/^a\+\|\(^a\+\)\@<=b\+
```

The reason why this works is that Vim will first search for `b`s and then look behind to see if that other part of the regex also matches. So the pattern gets anchored on `b` rather than `a` and doesn't suffer from the issue of trying to start a match on a region that already matched another expression.

Please note that zero-width lookups such as this one can have performance side effects, if the regex is too generic Vim might end up going pretty far trying to look for the start of a match. See [`:help /\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that directly nails exactly at the center of where my issue was.

Answer (score 3):

[I ran into this once.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58160050/4400820)

The short answer is even though `\zs` causes the match to start later, it « consumes » the `a`s before it.

The workaround is to use lookahead/behind, I believe. I’m not a master of vim’s syntax for that though; see `:help pattern`.

I think you just need `/\(^a\+\)\@<=b\+/`

Comment: Nitpick: you're missing the `^` on the lookbehind.

Comment: Should there also be `\(...\)`?  I.e. `\(^a\+\)\@<=`?

Comment: @caveman yeah probably

Answer (score 3):

There's an alternative and arguably cleaner method of achieving your goal.

By using Vim's syntax features to make `xA` a group that can only be found within `xB`, you can remove your `\zs` entirely, resulting in much simpler regular expressions:

```
syntax match xA /^a\+/ containedin=xB contained
syntax match xB /^a\+b\+/
```

[`containedin=XB`](http://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#:syn-containedin) means that `xA` can be found within `xB`, and [`contained`](http://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#:syn-contained) means that it cannot be found anywhere else (or more precisely, at the top level).

It's a little unclear from your question, but if you want `aaa` to be red even when it's not followed by `bbbb`, you can simplify even further:

```
syntax match xA /^a\+/ nextgroup=xB
syntax match xB /b\+/ contained
```

[`nextgroup=xB`](http://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#:syn-nextgroup) means that after a match for `xA`, Vim will check to see if `xB` immediately follows. As in the previous solution, `contained` in the `xB` definition means that strings of `b` characters elsewhere in the file will not be matched.