# Concealment causes color highlighting to not apply

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal

Following [my previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/syntax-highlighting-with-multiple-matches-with-zs/22431#22431), I have the same string `aaabbbb` that I am colorizing in the same way, except with the addition that I am now also trying to conceal the `a`s.

Here is the best that I got so far:

```
" here xB is not matched
syntax match xA /^a\+/ conceal transparent
syntax match xB /\(^a\+\)\@<=b\+/
highlight xA ctermfg=red
highlight xB ctermfg=blue
```

But the problem is that, while the `a`s get concealed as expected, they don't get colorized.

But, if I remove the concealment, colorization works fine.  I.e. this colorizes just fine (but obviously doesn't conceal the `a`s):

```
" here xB is not matched
syntax match xA /^a\+/
syntax match xB /\(^a\+\)\@<=b\+/
highlight xA ctermfg=red
highlight xB ctermfg=blue
```

**Q1:** How to colorize and conceal at the same time?

**Q2:** I feel that I am missing some fundamental knowledge about how `vim` applies match/highlight.  What is going on here?  Is the concealment causing vim to not see the text during the syntax highlighting stage? I mean, it's the same match statement.  So vim saw the text and applied the concealment, but somehow thought to not apply the color to it.  What's am I missing in the internal vim workflow?

---

*Update:* This seems to work, but I am not sure why.

```
" here xB is not matched
syntax match xA /^a\+/
syntax match xB /\(^a\+\)\@<=b\+/
highlight xA ctermfg=red
highlight xB ctermfg=blue
syntax match xAConceal /^a\+/ conceal transparent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, `transparent` prevents coloring the text in any ways.

I would expect the following to work

```
syntax match xA /^a\+/ conceal
syntax match xB /\(^a\+\)\@<=b\+/
highlight xA ctermfg=red
highlight xB ctermfg=blue
```

Comment: Ooo.  YES.  I'm DUMBIE.  Thanks!