# Disable spell checking for URLs in BibTeX

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, spell-checking

I would like to disable spell checking for the URLs in my BibTeX (`.bib`) files. I was able to disable spell checking for the citation keys (`author-year` or `author+year`) as follows:

```
autocmd FileType bib
\ syntax match _key '\w\+[-+]\d\d\d\d'
\ containedin=bibKey
\ contains=@NoSpell
```

For the URLs, I have the pattern (`\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+`), but I cannot figure out what to put in `containedin`. The best I came up with is `containedin=bibQuote,bibBrace`, that works but it breaks syntax highlighting for everything that comes after the URL.

P.S. I would like to disable spell checking for the `author` and `journal` fields as well.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if it would be simpler to only enable spell in title/abstract/notes fields? I don't have spell set in bib files at all, but I also don't know the syntax files for bib very well.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I agree, that would be great.

Comment: Oof, the bib syntax file only really defines keys and fields; there's no way to target specific ones, AFAICT, so I'm not sure I can figure this out

Comment: You might be able to `hi link _key bibQuote` to get syntax highlighting back

Answer (score 7):

> For the URLs, I have the pattern `\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+`, but I cannot figure out what to put in `containedin`. The best I came up with is `containedin=bibQuote,bibBrace`, that works but it breaks syntax highlighting for everything that comes after the URL.

This pattern actually works, *except* in cases where the URL is at the end of the field value and ends up eating the ending `}` or `"` of the `containedin` group.

You can easily fix this by making your URL pattern more restrictive in what it accepts. For example, simply disallowing these two characters should be enough to solve the problem: `\w+://[^[:space:]}"]+`. (Of course, you can decide to be even more restrictive in what you accept in a URL, as long as you don't include those two characters, which should be encoded in valid URLs anyways.)

> P.S. I would like to disable spell checking for the `author` and `journal` fields as well.

I have a suggestion, not exactly for what you asked here, but it might solve your problem with spelling of BibTeX files.

Instead of deciding what *not* to spell, you could do the opposite and specify only the parts that you actually *want* to spell.

For example, you might decide to only spell the contents of fields `title` (also `booktitle`, which ends in the same suffix), `type` and `note`.

In that case, you can use the following pair of rules:

```
syntax region bibSpellBrace
  \ start=/\(\(title\|type\|note\)\s*=\s*\)\@<={/
  \ end=/\ze}/ skip=/\(\\[{}]\)/
  \ contained containedin=bibBrace
  \ contains=@Spell
syntax region bibSpellQuote
  \ start=/\(\(title\|type\|note\)\s*=\s*\)\@<="/
  \ end=/\ze"/ skip=/\(\\"\)/
  \ contained containedin=bibQuote
  \ contains=@Spell
```

Add these to a file such as `~/.vim/after/syntax/bib.vim` to load the rules automatically (after loading the default syntax rules) when editing BibTeX files.

The rules above mirror the `bibBrace` and `bibQuote` rules from the default BibTeX syntax, however:

1. They use a zero-width look-behind match to check on the field name, so the rules only get enabled on the specified fields. See `:help /\@<=`. Note that using `\zs` doesn't work here, since those tokens (with the field name and quote or brace) have already been consumed. The zero-width look-behind still works fine here. (For a more detailed explanation, see question [“Syntax highlighting with multiple matches with `\zs`”](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22429/18609).)
2. They use a `\ze` on the ending pattern, to avoid consuming the closing brace or quote and let the container `bibBrace` or `bibQuote` see those.
3. They use `containedin` to insert themselves in the proper location of the syntax, specifically inside `bibBrace` or `bibQuote`.

Note that since the syntax for BibTeX uses `syntax spell default` (which is the default behavior, see `:help :syn-spell` for details), that means that as soon as you mention `@Spell` in a single rule of your syntax (such as the two above do), Vim will *only* spell check the contents of the matching groups.

This behavior is the same as the explicit `syntax spell notoplevel`, but it turns out the explicit setting is not really needed here, since the default behavior already detects we're explicitly listing the only bits we want to be checked for spelling.

Comment: Wow. A single touch of a truly expert mind and everything works as expected. Abracadabra. On top of that, you explained everything with utmost clarity so that I will not struggle with a similar problem again. Thank you so much for taking time to help me!

Comment: Happy to help and glad that it seems that this helped you!